# R, ggvis graphing from two data frames that both need to be grouped by

Tags: r, ggvis

I'm creating a stacked bar graph with multiple horizontal lines running through it. This is done in a Shiny app. The user picks an option and depending on what it is, there could be either 2 or 3 horizontal lines.

here is a minimal reproducible example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(a=as.factor(rep(1:10,2)), 
                  b=sample(1:5,20, replace=T),
                  c=c(rep("apple",10), rep("banana",10)) )
df1 <- df1[order(df1$a, df1$c),]
df2 <- data.frame(a=as.factor(rep(1:10,2)),
                  i=c(rep(3,10),rep(4,10)),
                  j=c(rep("red",10), rep("green",10))  )

> df1
    a b      c
1   1 5  apple
11  1 2 banana
2   2 3  apple
12  2 3 banana
3   3 1  apple
13  3 2 banana
4   4 3  apple
14  4 1 banana
5   5 4  apple
15  5 3 banana
6   6 4  apple
16  6 2 banana
7   7 3  apple
17  7 4 banana
8   8 5  apple
18  8 1 banana
9   9 5  apple
19  9 2 banana
10 10 1  apple
20 10 3 banana
> df2
    a i     j
1   1 3   red
2   2 3   red
3   3 3   red
4   4 3   red
5   5 3   red
6   6 3   red
7   7 3   red
8   8 3   red
9   9 3   red
10 10 3   red
11 11 3   red
12  1 4 green
13  2 4 green
14  3 4 green
15  4 4 green
16  5 4 green
17  6 4 green
18  7 4 green
19  8 4 green
20  9 4 green
21 10 4 green
22 11 4 green

ggvis(data=df1, x=~a, y=~b) %>%
    group_by(c) %>%
    layer_bars(fill=~c) %>%
    layer_paths(data=df2, x=~a, y=~i, strokeWidth:=2)
```

which gives me the following graph (it'll look different each time because of sample() ).

[image]

But I don't want the inverse Z in the middle. What I want is two parallel lines that are grouped by df2$j. But I'm not sure how to go about that with two data frames in my ggvis.

The reason I have df2 in a long form is because the user could choose an option that would create more than 2 horizontal lines. I don't want to use if and else to control for that. In my actual code, df1 and df2 are both reactives.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Seems like you need to give `layer_paths` a dataset grouped on the `y` variable.  Does `layer_paths(data = group_by(df2, i), x = ~a, y = ~i, strokeWidth:=2)` do what you want?

Comment: Yes! Thank you. Didn't know you could use group_by that way. very useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give `layer_paths` a dataset grouped on your y variable so the horizontal lines will be drawn separately for each group.

To do this, you can use `data = group_by(df2, i)` instead of `data = df2`.

And your code and plot would look like:

```
ggvis(data=df1, x=~a, y=~b) %>%
    group_by(c) %>%
    layer_bars(fill=~c) %>%
    layer_paths(data = group_by(df2, i), x = ~a, y = ~i, strokeWidth:=2)
```

[image]